# Would this PCIe 2.1 Video Card Work on My PCIe 1 Motherboard?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, compatibility, pci-express

I've got a PCIe mobo, more precisely: ASUS M2N-X based on nForce 520. Would a PCIe 2.1 VC like the Radeon HD5770 work with my mobo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, PCI 2.1 is backwards compatible with PCIe 2.0/1.0. While it will run slightly slower, it will only be a few FPS.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't have a problem as PCIe 2.0/2.1 is backwards compatible with 1, but it won't operate at full capacity.

Edit: meaning, it won't be as fast as it would in a PCIe 2.1 or 2.0 slot. I doubt you'd notice much of a difference though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is entirely true, right now, I am trying to use a X1 PCIe 2.1 card (2.5gbe network) into any of the 2.0 or even PCIe 3.0 and the card does not get recognized, at all but in a modern computer it gets recognized normally, there's no problem with the mobo either